# Populating string with spaces in ListView

Tags: java, javafx

please, could you help me?

i have listview in java
in ObservableList or ArrayList i have strings like

`CTAudSvc                2760
ctfmon                  6176
dllhost                 6464
dllhost                14656
DLLML                  10920
DMedia                  6768
dwm                     1104
explorer                6492
chrome                  2964`

but when i put it into listview i see something like this:

`CTAudSvc          2760
ctfmon                  6176
dllhost       656
DLLML              10920
DMedia            6768
dwm                     1104
explorer           6492
chrome              2964`

In code, i have nothing special, so if you know what makes it ignoring some spaces, please help me.

```
ArrayList<String> processListUnsorted = new ArrayList<String>();
...
Sting input...
processListUnsorted.add(input.trim());
...
List<String> sortedApps = processListUnsorted.stream() .sorted(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
...
ObservableList<String> sortedAppsFinal = FXCollections.observableArrayList(sortedApps);
...
somelistview.setItems(sortedAppsFinal);</code>
```

Comment: Are you sure there are spaces missing or is it just a non monospace font in the UI?

Comment: You should look into using `Cell Factory`. Split the `String`. Then use an `HBox`. Use two `Labels` in the `HBox`. Set the first `Label` to `HBox.setHGrow("Always");`

Comment: Its output of command from powershell "Get-Process | Format-Table -Property Name, ID".

Comment: Wouldn't representing the data with an appropriate class (with `String` and `int` properties), and displaying these in a table view with two columns, be a better approach for this?

Comment: Thats good idea too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of achieving this but I would take James_D approach.

You should look into using Cell Factory. Split the String. Then use an HBox. Use two Labels in the HBox. Set the first Label to `HBox.setHgrow(label, "ALWAYS");` and `setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewExperiments extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("ListView Experiment 1");

        List<String> data = new ArrayList();
        data.add("CTAudSvc                2760");
        data.add("ctfmon                  6176");
        data.add("dllhost                 6464");

        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data));
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>()
        {
            Label label = new Label();              
            Label label2 = new Label();
            HBox hBox = new HBox(label, label2);

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
            {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
                else {
                    label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    HBox.setHgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);
                    String[] splitString = item.split("\\s+");
                    label.setText(splitString[0]);
                    label2.setText(splitString[1]);
                    setGraphic(hBox);
                }
            }
        });

        HBox hbox = new HBox(listView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(hbox, 300, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great idea. Thank you, i will try it.

Comment: It would be better to avoid recreation of the `HBox`+`Label`s by creating those nodes in an initializer and simply filling them according to the content. Furthermore you create the nodes even if you do not need them. This should also be avoided, whether the code is inside a `updateItem` method or not.

Comment: Sadly, I don't always remember where everything goes. I hope the update covers all the things you addressed.

Comment: I have tried your code and its working very good. Thank you very much for your solution.